# What kind of information is important to share in the README.md of an Open Source game?

Tags: open-source, documentation

I want to write a very small and amateur game for toddlers and I want to make it open source.

I'm trying to figure out what I need to put in the README.md. A general approach could be:

> ## Building a Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich
>
> ### Introduction
>
> In this project, you will build a Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich (PB&J).
>
> ### Getting Started
>
> Before you build a PB&J, you will need to:
> ***YOUR WORKING ENVIRONMENT HERE***
>
> ### Dependencies
>
> In order to build a PB&J, you will need the following supplies:
> ***YOUR INGREDIENTS HERE***
>
> ### Instructions
>
> Once you've collected your dependencies, to build your PB&J:
> ***YOUR ASSEMBLY INSTRUCTIONS HERE***
>
> ### Output
>
> ***YOUR EXPECTED OUTPUT HERE***

What would you expect to read for an Open Source game in order to be able to use it or contribute to it?

Would this be enough?

Comment: The `README.md` file is specific to GitHub (not open source in general) and is the first thing people get to read when viewing your project. What to put there depends on what you want to communicate to those readers. We can't read your mind, so we can't know what you want to tell these people.

Comment: @Philipp while `README.md` is GitHub-specific, `README` is common to a lot of opensource projects, including those that were created before git became widespread.

Comment: @Philipp Why should a markdown file be GitHub specific? Any software project since the 80ies comes, more or less with a readme file (or however you want to call it). I know that I can put whatever I want, I am asking for whatever you need to be able to use my project and to contribute in order to make it useful for others.

Comment: @Pitto You asked specifically about a `README.md` file, not a general `README` file. But at least I got you to reveal a detail about what you actually want to communicate on your GitHub project file: How to use your project and how to contribute.

Comment: @Philipp md is just markdown, it is not a GitHub exclusive. It would be like saying that html is a GitHub exclusive. Markdown perfectly works also on Bitbucket, just to name another and Gitlab and other platforms too. As you can see markdown is perfectly rendered also here in StackExchange (in my post), this once again speaks about its usefulness. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

If you share an open source game poeple should be able to build it in their local dev environment. If you add installing and building isntructions and which tools you used will helpful. Also, if you used some private/secrets keys like api key etc. keep them secret don't include them project and indicate people you used this kind of apis/keys.

Comment: So basically: clone your repo, follow the instructions, do you have a working game? If not, fix it until this does work.